# How to add properties with a specific type into gremlinpython?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

Currently i am trying to import via [gremlinpython](https://pypi.org/project/gremlinpython/) a large graph from igraph programmatically . I am rather new to gremlin and the endpoints i may use it with. The problem i currently face is that a property in a node/edge can have multiple types. (E.g.: -> Bool or None-type | Int, Long, etc..)

I've noticed no error when importing it into this [gremlin-server](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/downloads.html) (is this called Apache TinkerGraph-Server? How should i call this?). It seems that the types of same properties can be arbitrary.

However, when using [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org/) i receive multiple errors:
`gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: Value [XXX] is not an instance of the expected data type for property key [YYY] and cannot be converted. Expected: class <SomeClass>, found: class <SomeOtherClass>`

E.g. executing:

```py
conn = DriverRemoteConnection("ws://localhost:8182/gremlin", "g")
remote_graph = traversal().withRemote(conn)

remote_graph.addV().property("test", 10000).next()
remote_graph.addV().property("test", 100000000000000000000000).next()  # <- Causes an error on JanusGraph
```

It is possible for me to cast some properties into other datatypes (Bool/None-Type-> -1,0,1), so i can avoid this error. But i am not sure how i should handle the above provided example. Is there a way to explicitly set the type (for at least numeric types) of a property, so that the server knows to store it e.g. as a Long/BigInt instead of as a Int? Especially since in python3 there is no distincion between long(/bigint) and int anymore.

So specifically is there something like the following?:
E.g. executing:

```py
remote_graph.addV().property("test", 10000).asLong().next()
remote_graph.addV().property("test", 10000, <Type: Long>).next()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gremlin does have a [special class](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.4.10/gremlin-python/src/main/jython/gremlin_python/statics.py#L27) for ensuring a Java `Long`. You can just do `long(10000)` given the appropriate import like: `from gremlin_python.statics import long`

Comment: Thanks. it does work with this import. Is this also documented somewhere?

Comment: it's not explicit as it should be. i will make an addition to the reference documentation.